# Javascript inline replace undefined with empty string

Tags: javascript, string, undefined, ternary-operator

I have this function:

```
function callWS(input) {
    var output = {
        "type"  : input["type"]  || "",
        "mark"  : input["mark"]  || "",
        "model" : input["model"] || "",
        "year"  : input["year"]  || ""
    };

    return output;
}
```

I want the user to call this function in many ways:

```
callWS(); ==> {"type":"","mark":"","model":"","year":""}
callWS({"type":"moto"}); ==> {"type":"moto","mark":"","model":"","year":""}
callWS({"type":"moto","mark":"audi"}); ==> {"type":"moto","mark":"audi","model":"","year":""}
```

And in case a parameters is undefined, to initialize it as an *empty string*. Currently my function does not work in the first case, but in the other is working.

When I call it like `callWS()` I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
```

To be honest I don't know why it works for the 2 and 3 case but I need to make it work for the first case also. I know that if I use:

```
if (input["type"])
```

will do the trick but I need an inline solution. Is this possible somehow?

Comment: You have to supply `input` itself with default value too. Just add `input = input || {}` to the beginning of `callWS`

Comment: Define your function as `function callWS(input = {})`.

Comment: @torazaburo - the project does not include ES6

Comment: @François Wahl - Unfortunately the project does not use jQuery, it doesn't use any external library.

Comment: @paulalexandru hence the part, if you are not using jQuery you can write your own easily :)  I only used JavaScript in my example too but you already have it sorted anyway :)

Comment: @FrançoisWahl - True. Thank you for your solution, it's just that I was searching for the easiest solution, to add as less code as possible. But your solution might help others as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to supply `input` variable itself with default value too.

```
function callWS(input) {
   input = input || {};
   ...
}
```

Otherwise you access properties on unexisting (undefined) object which lead to error (what you have now).

On other hand accessing unexisting properties on existing object isn't treated as error in JS.

Comment: yes @torazaburo but he wants the object with properties created and not undefined

Comment: @torazaburo ok now I understood, sorry, the tree dots made me mistake

Answer (score 0):

In ES6, write this as

```
function callWS({type = "", mark = "", model = "", year = ""} = {}) {
  return {type, mark, model, year};
}
```

Here's another approach not involving ES6. Many libraries contain a `default` utility, which will apply some properties to another object if they are missing.

```
function deflt(obj, defaults) {
  var keys = Object.keys(defaults);
  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length: i++) {
    var key = keys[i];
    if (!(key in obj)) obj[key] = defaults[key];
  }
  return obj;
}
```

You can use this as follows:

```
function callWS(input) {
  input = input || {};
  deflt(input, {type: "", mark: "", model: "", year: ""});
  return input;
}
```

Note: as written this will return a modified version of the input. Adjust as necessary if this is not what you want.

Comment: Unfortunately, the project does not use ES6

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own `extend` method and use that.
That way you can have a default object, giving it which ever default values and then merge it with the object passed into the function.

```js
function extend(a, b){
    for(var key in b){
        if(b.hasOwnProperty(key)){
            a[key] = b[key];
        }
    }

    return a;
}

function callWS(input) {
    var defaultInput = {
        "type": "",
        "mark": "",
        "model":"",
        "year": ""
    }
    
    var output = extend(defaultInput, input);

    return output;
}

console.log(callWS());
console.log(callWS({"type":"moto"}));
console.log(callWS({"type":"moto","mark":"audi"}));
```